# Modifying a JS object's properties by passing the properties only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a plugin that accepts two parameters - height and width.  The consumers of this plugin may have a rectangle object, or a square object, or a polygon object, etc.  The names of their width/height may be different:

```
var square = { 
   width: 200,
   height: 200
}

var rectangle = { 
   Width: 200,
   tall: 200
}

var polygon = { 
   w: 200,
   h: 200
}
```

I'm trying to build a function that accepts width / height parameters and modifies them, so that the parent object is updated.  Something like this:

```
var alterStuff = function (width, height){
    width = 200;
    height = 200;
};

var obj = {width: "28", height: "34"};

alterStuff(obj.width, obj.height);

alert(obj.width);
```

The goal is that the consumer can pass in two primitive types, and the `alterStuff` function will update them on the object.

What pattern can be used to achieve this?  Right now the `obj` properties are not being updated - I see "28" in the alert, but I'd like to see "200" without passing in the object, since I don't know what the property names will be on that object in all cases.

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of property names, the three given here, or could it be anything?

Comment: @chelmerich - it could be anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you can't!

When you pass something to a function you pass it's value. If it's a primitive value, for example 5, you pass 5 to the function. If it's an object, actually it's a reference to an object and you pass that reference. This means that when you pass `obj.width` which has the value for example `45px` you pass just that string to the function and there is absolutely no connection to `obj`.

The only way to update properties on an object is to pass the object itself and the name of the property:

```
function change(obj, key, val) {
  obj[key] = val;
}

var obj = { width : 5 };
change(obj, 'width', 10);
```

---

In your particular situation you could make a best-effort at "guessing" the property names from the keys of the object. In the following example the widthKey and heightKey are optional, so if the user of the library function has a well behaved object, he doesn't need to pass them. Otherwise, he should pass them.

```
function updateSize(object, width, height, opt_widthKey, opt_heightKey) {
  // potential width properties:
  var widths = ['width', 'Width', 'w'];
  // potential height properties:
  var heights = ['height', 'Height', 'h'];

  var widthKey = opt_widthKey || getPropertyName(object, widths);
  if (!widthKey) throw new Error('Can not guess width property');

  var heightKey = opt_heightKey || getPropertyName(object, heights);
  if (!heightKey) throw new Error('Can not guess height property');

  object[widthKey] = width;
  object[heightKey] = height;
}

function getPropertyName(object, properties) {
  for (var i=0; i<properties.length; i++) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(properties[i]))
      return properties[i];
  }
}

// usage:

var obj = { width : 5, Height : 10 };
var notGood = { tall : 20, wide : 40 };

updateSize(obj, 100, 200);
updateSize(notGood, 100, 200, 'wide', 'tall');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass the object itself rather than its properties:

```
var alterStuff = function (obj){
    obj.width = 200;
    obj.height = 200;
};

var obj = {width: "28", height: "34"};

alterStuff(obj);
```

You might want to read [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good way to do what you want without passing the object. Perhaps you could return a 2 member array that the caller will be responsible for loading back into the correct place:

```
var alterStuff = function(width, height) {
    return [+width * 2, +height * 2];    // for example
}

var obj =  {width: "28", height: "34"};

var newValues = alterStuff(obj.width, obj.height);
obj.width = newValues[0];
obj.height = newValues[1];
```

Or, you could have the caller provide a callback function:

```
var alterStuff = function(width, height, callback) {
    // note: you may want to include some checks for undefined and that callback is a function
    callback(+width *2, +height * 2);
}

alterStuff(obj.width, obj.height, function(width, height) {
   obj.width = width;
   obj.height = height;
});
```

So now if I had:

```
var rectangle = { 
   Width: 200,
   tall: 200
}
```

I could call `alterStuff` like this:

```
alterStuff(rectangle.Width, rectangle.tall, function(Width, tall) {
    rectangle.Width = Width;
    rectangle.tall = tall;
});
```

And what names I choose for the "width" and "height" like properties are the callers choice.

Or Tibos' answer is another alternative where you pass in the key(s) when you call the function.